# Echoing jQuery script from PHP on upload form while using iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following HTML code for my file upload

```
<div id="status"></div>

<iframe name="upifrm" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upifrm">
<label for="fileinput" id="brsbtn" class="labtrigg">label</label> 
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="file" />
</form>

<div id="atchs"></div>
```

and at the end of my upload.php file I have

```
// . . . . . . . . . . . . .     
// $message declaration . . .

echo '<script>
parent.document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); 
parent.document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="'.$message.'";
$("#atchs", window.parent.document).after("<span>something</span>");
</script>';
```

the first two lines work perfectly (they are written in pure Javascript code), but I get the error on the third line

```
$("#atchs", window.parent.document).after("<span>something</span>");
```

"Object expected". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you call `$("#atchs", window.parent.document).("<span>something</span>");` in your iframe ? do you have jquery included in the iframe ?

Comment: Your first two lines are of conventional js why are you using jQuery method on third line ?

Comment: I have included jQuery on my main HTML file. Iframe is on this HTML file. Rikesh, I want to rewrite whole code in jQuery, so above code is just  an example. Thank you.

Comment: `window.parent.document` < are you sure that this doesn't result in `undefined`?

Comment: Bwoebi, yes I'm sure. I tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one
Make sure in your parent page youhave included `jQuery` file

```
top.jQuery("#atchs").html("<span>something</span>");
```

hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have jQuery included, there should be a function name here:

```
$("#atchs", window.parent.document).("<span>something</span>");
                                    ^^^
```

Something like `append`, `prepend`, `html`, `text`, or whatever you're trying to do. It cannot be just a dot and parentheses.